# pushout and homotopy

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose that we have tree spaces $A, B, C$ (let say CW-complexes). Are given two pairs of maps:

$$f_{0},g_{0}: A\rightarrow B $$
$$f_{1}, g_{1}: A\rightarrow C $$
such that $f_{0},g_{0}$ are homotopic and $f_{1},g_{1}$ are also homotopic.

Is it true that  $colim [B\leftarrow^{f_{0}} A\rightarrow^{f_{1}} C] $
and $colim[B\leftarrow^{g_{0}} A\rightarrow^{g_{1}} C]$ are weakly equivalent ?

Moreover, we assume that $g_{0}= i\circ f_{0}$ and $g_{1}=j\circ f_{1}$ where $i:B\rightarrow B $ and $j: C\rightarrow C$ are weak equivalences.

Comment: This is true for homotopy colimits. That's more or less why the notion of homotopy colimit was invented, to fix this defect of the usual colimit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Take $A=[0,1]$, $B=S^1$, $C=\text{point}$.  There is only one possible choice for $f_1$ and $g_1$.  There are many possible choices for $f_0$ and $g_0$, but they are all homotopic.  Choose $f_0$ to be constant, and choose $g_0$ to be surjective.  Then the pushout for $f$ is $S^1$, and the pushout for $g$ is a point.

UPDATE:
Here is an adjusted answer for the adjusted question.  Use the same spaces as before, but with the model $[0,1]/(0\sim 1)$ for $B=S^1$.  Define $f_0\colon A\to B$ by $f_0(t)=[t/2]$, and define $g_0$ by $g_0(t)=[t]$.  Define $h_s\colon B\to B$ by $h_s([t])=[\min(1,(1+s)t)]$, so $h_0=1$ and $h_1\circ f_0=g_0$.  Again the pushout for $f$ is $S^1$, and the pushout for $g$ is a point.

Comment: Sorry I have just seen your answer, I a added a condition in my question. Is there still an obvious counterexample  ? Thanks.

Comment: May be I'm missing something, but in your example $h_{1}$ is not a weak equivalence as it was assumed in the question. right ?

Comment: $h_1$ is homotopic to the identity, so of course it is a weak equivalence.